# Is there any way to check a Yml/Yaml file is valid ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

It should check all cases of imports, includes and custom variables. As of now I can see that ansible-playbook playbook.yml --list-tasks fails in few cases when we have custom variables. For example a yml having tasks only should not be a valid play. yml importing those tasks should be treated as valid ansible play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way templating etc works, the only way to know for sure beyond basic syntax checking (eg `--syntax-check` or `--list-tasks`) is to execute it. `--check-mode` can tell you some things if your playbook is written correctly to support it, and there are other tools around like `ansible-lint` that might help, but nothing short of executing the playbook will tell you 100%.